# Closeness of a number to mean.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, measure-theory

Let's say I am given mean $\mu$ and deviation $\sigma$ of a set of numbers.

I am now given $x$, a real number.

Depending on how close $x$ is to $\mu$, I need a measure starting from 100 going down to 0. 100 being the closest and 0 being the farthest away from $\mu$. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question is really unclear. What exactly are you trying to measure? Do you know the set of numbers? Please explain

Comment: It's not about measure theory, anyway

Comment: @amirbd89 I am not given the set of numbers. Just their $\mu$ and $\sigma$. When I am given a new number $x$ which lies between $\mu + 2\sigma$ and  $\mu - 2\sigma$, I have to output $y$. $y$ can range from 100 to 0. 100 should be the case where $\mu -x = 0$ and 0 $\mu -x or x - \mu = \mu + 2\sigma or \mu - 2\sigma$. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: since it reeks of normal distribution, try rescale its  pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about
$$
\frac{100}{1+\sigma|x-\mu|^2}?
$$
This is a smooth function of $x$ that is 100 when $x=\mu$ and goes to zero as $|x-\mu|\to\infty$.
You can change the decay rate by changing the constant $\sigma$.

Comment: Thanks. That kind of helped.